# Переход к фрагменту согласно дню недели

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, datetime

Делаю приложение с расписанием(просто как дополнение ко всему). Имеется активность с 6 фрагментами(не изящное решение). Каждый фрагмент это день недели, Необходимо сделать так чтобы при открытии этой активности, согласно дате сразу осуществлялся переход к тому фрагменту, который соответствует текущему дню недели. Но сами дни недели не менялись местами. Сейчас сделал только чтобы сначала открывался фрагмент с текущем днём недели, но он ставится на первое место, а остальные за ним. Типо такого: Ср Пн Вт Чт и т д. Вот код метода onCreate. В нём инициализируются фрагменты. Прошу навести на мысль

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    groupid = findViewById(R.id.groupid);
    date = findViewById(R.id.date);
    final GlobalVariable globalVariable = (GlobalVariable) getApplicationContext();
    username.setText(globalVariable.getUsername());
    groupid.setText(globalVariable.getIdgroup());
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d MMM");
    date.setText(format.format(new Date()));

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Monday(),"Пн");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Tuesday(),"Вт");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Wednesday(),"Ср");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Thursday(),"Чт");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Friday(),"Пт");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Saturday(),"Сб");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможное решение:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (dayOfWeek != 1) {            
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(dayOfWeek - 2);
}
```

Comment: по календарю первый день недели Воскресение - ваш код нужно корректировать

Comment: В условии это обрабатывается.

Comment: Воскресение под индексом 1, а у автора вопроса первым идет понедельник и кстати calendar.setTime лишний. весь код неверен

Comment: В принципе заработало. Но пришлось метод getItem подправлять. Пытался сделать через setPrimaryItem, но вышла дичь. Был выход за пределы массива. Спасибо за решение!

Comment: Решение сделано на "коленке". Главное, поняли реализацию. =) Не за что!

Comment: Ещё 1 небольшой вопросик... Это приложение для студентов вуза, колледжа, техникума и т д(ни в коем случае не программный продукт). Как и в любом подобном приложении есть вкладки с новостями, событиями и тому подобное. В принципе всё это реализовано на firebase(в моём случае). Но вот с этим самым расписанием и новостями проблема. Забивать бдшку данными для этого очень долго и легко запутаться. Сейчас ищу сервис для этого, для удобного хранения данных, удобного доступа к ним, удобной работы с этими данными(редактирование, добавление). Если есть опыт работы с этими сервисами, прошу помочь...

Comment: Или может быть в самом Firebase есть такая возможность.  Для удобного хранения большого объёма данных, и лёгкого редактирования при желании

Comment: Firebase - на мой взгляд, самый доступный бэкенд для Android и, главное, бесплатный до поры. Возможно, есть какие-то библиотеки для удобной работы с ним - я использовал только штатные средства.

Comment: Ок, понял. Ещё раз спасибо за ответ.